# Webrtc_ros fatal error: adapted_video_track_source.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

I try using error msg to search on  google but have no solution

Thanks !
**My system : windows10/ VMWARE/ ubuntu 18.04 / ROS melodic**

**My webrtc insall step**

```
cd ~
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
sudo vim ~/.bashrc 
export PATH="$PATH:~/depot_tools"
source ~/.bashrc

mkdir webrtc-checkout
cd webrtc-checkout
fetch --nohooks webrtc
gclient sync
```

**My webrtc_ros install step:**

```
cd catkin_ws/src

git clone https://github.com/RobotWebTools/webrtc_ros.git

cd ..

catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="webrtc_ros"

**Below is my error log:** 

[ 64%] Building CXX object webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/CMakeFiles/webrtc_ros_server.dir/src/ros_video_capturer.cpp.o
In file included from /home/jetbot/catkin_ws/src/webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/src/ros_video_capturer.cpp:1:0:
/home/jetbot/catkin_ws/src/webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/include/webrtc_ros/ros_video_capturer.h:6:10: fatal error: webrtc/media/base/adapted_video_track_source.h: No such file or directory
 #include <webrtc/media/base/adapted_video_track_source.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/CMakeFiles/webrtc_ros_server.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/CMakeFiles/webrtc_ros_server.dir/src/ros_video_capturer.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/CMakeFiles/webrtc_ros_server.dir/src/ros_video_capturer.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/async_web_server_cpp/websocket_connection.hpp:5:0,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/async_web_server_cpp/websocket_request_handler.hpp:5,
                 from /home/jetbot/catkin_ws/src/webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/src/webrtc_web_server.cpp:11:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/async_web_server_cpp/websocket_message.hpp:15:19: warning: missing terminating ' character
 #    warning I don't know how to create a packed struct with your compiler
                   ^
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:560: recipe for target 'webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/CMakeFiles/webrtc_ros_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/CMakeFiles/webrtc_ros_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407301/webrtc_ros-fatal-error:-adapted_video_track_source.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [asps946701](https://answers.ros.org/users/109763/asps946701/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-03**:
The `webrtc_ros` depends on `webrtc`. Make sure `webrtc` is installed properly.

**Comment by [asps946701](https://answers.ros.org/users/109763/asps946701/) on 2022-10-03**:
I will install webrtc. Thanks you !!

**Comment by [asps946701](https://answers.ros.org/users/109763/asps946701/) on 2022-10-06**:
Do you have webrtc_ros insatll guide after ros was installed.
I was installed webrtc but it got many error. Trying some solution but also fail .Thnaks
Part of error :
-/opt/ros/melodic/include/webrtc/media/base/adapted_video_track_source.h:16:10: fatal error: absl/types/optional.h: No such file or directory
#include "absl/types/optional.h"

-/home/jetbot/catkin_ws/src/webrtc_ros/src/ros_video_renderer.cpp:19:36: error: ‘I420BufferInterface’ is not a member of ‘webrtc’
const rtc::scoped_refptrwebrtc::I420BufferInterface& buffer = frame.video_frame_buffer()->ToI420();

-/home/jetbot/catkin_ws/src/webrtc_ros/src/ros_video_renderer.cpp:21:22: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
cv::Mat bgra(buffer->height(), buffer->width(), CV_8UC4);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the following error:

```
/home/jetbot/catkin_ws/src/webrtc_ros/webrtc_ros/include/webrtc_ros/ros_video_capturer.h:6:10: fatal error: webrtc/media/base/adapted_video_track_source.h: No such file or directory
 #include <webrtc/media/base/adapted_video_track_source.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Basically, the `webrtc_ros` depends on `webrtc`. Therefore, please make sure `webrtc` is installed before compilation.

On the other hand, I suggest installing pre-built binaries using `apt` because it automatically takes care of installing dependencies. Please see below:

```
$ sudo apt install ros-melodic-webrtc
$ sudo apt install ros-melodic-webrtc-ros
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asps946701](https://answers.ros.org/users/109763/asps946701/) on 2022-10-13**:
Hi , I used apt install   "ros-melodic-webrtc" and "ros-melodic-webrtc-ros" but it got same error.

When I go to path : "/opt/ros/melodic/include/webrtc/media/base/" , I found  .h file name is :"adaptedvideotracksource.h".

Should I modify in "ros_video_capturer.h" file : "#include <webrtc/media/base/adapted_video_track_source.h>" to "#include <webrtc/media/base/adaptedvideotracksource.h>" ?

Thanks!

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-14**:
In the original question, you are trying to install `webrtc_ros` from the source. I advised installing pre-built binaries using `apt`. It should work well. However, you are reporting the same error. Therefore, I request you enumerate all of the commands you are using.

**Comment by [asps946701](https://answers.ros.org/users/109763/asps946701/) on 2022-10-14**:
Sorry ,I may have misunderstood.

If I use apt to install webrtc_ros , I will not require to build webrtc_ros from source ?

Now I install webrtc_ros from apt command is no problem.

thank you very much

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-14**:\

> If I use apt to install `webrtc_ros` , I will not require to build `webrtc_ros` from source ?

Yes. You are right. You do not need to build from source.

> Now I install webrtc_ros from apt command is no problem.

I am glad you made it work. May I request you to click on the check mark symbol, ✔ icon, located at the top left side of this answer? It will mark this question as answered.

**Comment by [asps946701](https://answers.ros.org/users/109763/asps946701/) on 2022-10-14**:
OK Thanks you very much !